# Open my Own Mac App Preferences

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I am newbie in Cocoa Application.
I want to programmatically open my application's preferences window

By googling, 
I can just found -->
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"MyApp.prefPane"];"

Any help would be appreciated.---

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the preference window just like any other within your app:

In App Delegate class:

```
- (IBAction)showPreferencePanel:(id)sender {
    if (!_preferenceController)
        _preferenceController = [[PreferenceController alloc] init];

    [_preferenceController showWindow:self];
}
```

Where `PreferenceController` is:

```
@interface PreferenceController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate, NSToolbarDelegate, FontChooserViewDelegate>
...
@end
```

And in `MainMenu.xib` the `showPreferencePanel` method is hooked in like this:

[image]